# How to integrate SQL with Windows forms?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I am having some problems with my mini-project.

I have to check if the name and password in the `TextBox` text field match the SQL database. If the password and name match the database, the user will be transferred over to another form. Otherwise, it will display an error message.

Right now. I can't determine whether the name and password entered in the `TextBox` text matches the SQL Database.

I am not using Data Binding for this project; this is just a normal database application.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PasswordtextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! Enter password !", "Warning");
    }
    else
    { 
        if (StaffUserIDcomboBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Warning!");
        }

        string strSql = "Select UserLogin From UserLogin Where UserLoginID=" + int.Parse(StaffUserIDcomboBox1.Text);
        UserClass1 userClass = new UserClass1();
        SqlDataReader UserLogin_ID = userClass.GetUserID();

        userClass.executeDataCommand(strSql);

        int rowCount = 0;
        if (UserLogin_ID.HasRows)
        {
            while (UserLogin_ID.Read()) 
            {
                rowCount++;
            }

            DisplayLabel.Text = rowCount.ToString();
            UserLogin_ID.Close();

            //pass value to form2 if valid
            string userid = StaffUserIDcomboBox1.Text;
            parent.setCurentUser(userid);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Results Found! Please Try again!");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting now?

Comment: Take a beginner programming book. Read it, learn programming. Come back when you realize that "I got an error" is a bad statement and that we expect you to at least spend so much brain power on your problem to tell us WHAT ERROR YOU GET. "It does not work" is not exactly helpfull. Stackoverflow is not a programming course replacement. And normal projects use databinding. And MVC (Model View Controller).

Comment: @Kangkan Well, there isn't any error. It just debugged as per normal but it did check if the password matches the database or not. And simply just skip through and proceed on to the other Forms.

Comment: @TomTom Sorry for my poor phrasing. The problem is that there are no error stated, Even when the pass word doesn't match the DATABASE, it will still continue to next form. What i am using is TDBMS (Relatinal Database Management System)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not locate any code that checks for the password match in the database. Generally you should have a method that validate the user along with the password like

```
private bool ValidateUser(String UserName, string HashedPassword)
{
    //Use datareader etc to query
    // SQL Query
    string strSql = "Select UserLogin From UserLogin Where UserLoginID=" + UserName + " UserPassword = " + HashedPassword;
    //check for returned rows count
    //return true if found                
}
```

Comment: And when you do this, **by all means** AVOID just concatenating together your SQL statements like this!! This is a wide-open invitation for **SQL Injection Attacks** - use **parametrized queries**!! ALWAYS - no exception

Answer (score 0):

Put a ***BREAK;*** after the messsagebox.show code.